# AWS Cloudformation template - user pool app client hosted ui login url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cloudformation

Is there a way to retrieve the login page url for a cognito user pool app client from the cloudformation template?

I currently have two projects: one for a spa webapp end one for the aws stack to host and serve it.
In terms of automation it would be perfect to have the spa project pipeline retrieving any necessary url from the aws stack via cli (e.g.: `sam describe-stack` or such) before assets compilation, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudFormation [Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) and [Import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) them into templates that need them.

The [CloudFormation Cognito User Pool documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#aws-resource-cognito-userpool-return-values) has a return value "ProviderURL". You would do something like this at the bottom of your CloudFormation template that creates the User Pool.

```
Resources:
  UserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties: 
      UserPoolName: Example
      (etc)
  Outputs:
    UserPoolURL:
      Value: !GetAtt 'UserPool.ProviderURL'
      Export:
        Name: "UserPoolURL"
```

Then you would do something like this in the CloudFormation template that needs to reference the URL.

```
Resources:
  ResourceName:
    Type: AWS::Whatever
    Properties: 
      URL: !ImportValue UserPoolURL
```

The code might not be quite right as I haven't tested it, but I've done this many times over the years and it should be about right if not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The Sign Up and Login URLs are built from the UserPoolClient. The following is a minimal SAM template that creates a UserPool, and UserPoolClient and generates Sign Up and Login URLs as outputs.

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Parameters:
  userPoolName:
    Type: String
    Description: The domain name for the Cognito User Pool
    Default: my-unique-pool-name
  callbackDomain:
    Type: String
    Description: URL that will be used for cognito callbacks
    Default: my-app.example.com
Resources:
  MyUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Ref userPoolName
      Schema:
        - Name: email
          AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Required: true
          StringAttributeConstraints:
            MinLength: '0'
            MaxLength: '2048'
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 8
          RequireLowercase: true
          RequireNumbers: true
          RequireSymbols: true
          RequireUppercase: true
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
  MyUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      ClientName: !Ref userPoolName
      UserPoolId: !Ref MyUserPool
      GenerateSecret: false
      CallbackURLs:
        - !Sub 'https://${callbackDomain}/'
      LogoutURLs:
        - !Sub 'https://${callbackDomain}/logout'
      AllowedOAuthFlows:
        - code
        - implicit
      AllowedOAuthScopes:
        - email
        - openid
        - profile
      AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient: true
      SupportedIdentityProviders:
        - COGNITO
  MyUserPoolDomain:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolDomain
    Properties:
      Domain: !Ref userPoolDomain
      UserPoolId: !Ref MyUserPool
Outputs:
  SignUpUrl:
    Description: Cognito Sign Up URL
    Value: !Sub 'https://${userPoolDomain}.auth.${AWS::Region}.amazoncognito.com/signup?response_type=code&client_id=${MyUserPoolClient}&redirect_uri=https://${callbackDomain}/'
  LoginUrl:
    Description: Cognito Login URL
    Value: !Sub 'https://${userPoolDomain}.auth.${AWS::Region}.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=${MyUserPoolClient}&redirect_uri=https://${callbackDomain}/'
```